# javascript: How do you use a function from the importing module in a function from the imported module/file

Tags: javascript, import, export

So I have a module

```
import {childFunction} from './child.js'
var parent = (function(){
  function parentFunction(){
    alert('parent hello');

   }


})();
```

Then in **child.js**

```
export function childFunction(){
  alert('child hello');
  parentFunction();
}
```

When I try to run this it says parentFunction is undefined. Am I misunderstanding a concept here or am I using the wrong functionality?

Is it possible to do what I'm trying to but in a different way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Two modules cannot import *each other*

That creates a circular dependency that cannot be resolved.

#### You could, instead, *pass* the parent function *to* the child function

That allows you to get around this.

```
child.js:

export function childFunction(parentFunctionPart2){
  alert('child hello');
  parentFunctionPart2();
}
```

```
parent.js:

import {childFunction} from "child.js"

function parentFunction(){
    childFunction(parentFunctionPart2)
}

function parentFunctionPart2(){
    // stuff that needs to provided to childFunction
}
```

Comment: is this called dependency injection or is that something else?

Comment: Yes it is - you are passing to the childFunction a dependency. I generally avoid it because it causes irritation when trying to debug, because it is hard to see quickly in code where the parentFunctionPart2 is being called (since the childFunction in general may use a different name for the function)